# Interfacing a Rpi with absolute encoder using RS-422 (SSI)

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial, signal-processing

So I am working on a project that requires me reading from an absolute encoder. It uses SSI (RS-422 protocol) and the datasheet is the following: https://www.hohner-elektrotechnik.de/upload/data-sheet-series-pzk-eng_1652102278.pdf . For my application I would need around 140 queries per second.

I was thinking on using a Raspberry Pi 4+ to query it, but I am a bit lost in terms of what to do/whether this is feasible/whether I need more hardware or not. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be feasible using a $1 MCU, with an added RS-422 transceiver. There's no question that a Rpi 4+ would be gross over-kill in terms of processing power and capability. And I'm certain there must be some RS-422 shields for it. (Or whatever they call add-on boards these days.) Most of what matters is your overall application. I'd suggest that you write out for us the important inputs and their servicing needs, the important outputs and their servicing needs, and important processing steps you require in between these two. Closed loop control? You need to say so, too.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do with the encoder data once you get it. If you want to send it out on wireless or network, then something running linux would be best because it would be easy to port the data to something else and require less code as you can download git projects and languages to the rpi4 and run them with little effort. You could also save the data to a file ect.

A microprocessor will usually require c code and some understanding, and you could pipe the data out on a uart, I2C bus or spi port. Some can do TCP/IP stacks but it is much more difficult to implement on most platforms.